# "Manually configure SSID and passphrase for LocalOnlyHotspot in android studio?"

Tags: android, hotspot

I'm trying to create a WiFi hotspot on the newer versions of `Android`, the hotspot does not need internet access, just a local network. I want to be able to set the SSID and passphrase of the hotspot manually but cannot find a way to do this from an android app. (The idea is to have a **Raspberry Pi** device listening for the hotspot, to connect and send 'data' once it is in range - for this to happen the SSID and passphrase need to be known/configured beforehand.)

I've tried using `WifiManager`'s method `startLocalOnlyHotspot()`; however, this method generates a random SSID and passphrase, which won't help me.

I did manage to find some functions that would be very helpful in generating a hotspot [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/modules/Wifi/framework/java/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java;drc=master;l=3867?q=func:setSoftApConfiguration). The WifiManager.java class has the `setSoftApConfiguration()` method and also has the `startTetheredHotspot()`; however, they don't seem to be available for use in Android Studio. Is there a reason these methods don't work?

I also came across the same functions that don't work [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/SoftApConfiguration).

My question is, can I configure a hotspot and set its **SSID** and passphrase manually on the newer versions of android? (Preferable without needing to insert a SIM card as well, but that is another issue)

Comment: Does anyone have an answer on that? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is NO, you cannot configure the hotspot.

1. Only system apps can configure the hotspot. To make your app a system app, you need to sign it with the same platform key which the oem uses.
2. setSoftApConfiguration() is a proctected/hidden API, you can get it in android studio if you use a custom SDK with exposed APIs or third party SDKs, but it still won't work without System privileges.

For android 13 and 14 you can configure the LocalOnlyHotSpot.
Your app should have "android.permission.NEARBY_WIFI_DEVICES" permission like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NEARBY_WIFI_DEVICES"
    android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
```

You should invoke a hidden API in the sdk using reflection like this

```
fun startLocalOnlyHotspotWithConfig(
            context: Context,
            config: SoftApConfiguration,
            executor: Executor?,
            callback: WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback
        ) {
            val wifiManager = context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
            WifiManager::class.java.getMethod(
                "startLocalOnlyHotspot", SoftApConfiguration::class.java, Executor::class.java,
                WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback::class.java,
            ).invoke(wifiManager, config, executor, callback)
       }
```

This method accepts a SoftApConfiguration as one the parameters

Again for creating a softApConfiguration use relection to invoke SoftApConfiguration.Builder().build().

**NB: Here the hotspot icon in the notification bar will not be turned on but the desired localOnlyHotspot is created.**